# Cannot get out of while loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to write a program where I get a userInput and keep getting the userInput until the user enters "quit". However, the while loop does not stop even though I enter quit. I thought it has to do something with the nextLine() function but not sure. I would appreciate your help.

Here's the code below: (I have java.util.Scanner imported)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        while (userInput != "quit" ){
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            userInput = in.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Never reaches here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        while (!userInput.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            userInput = in .nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Never reaches here");
    }
}
```